# Multiselect.js post via ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-ui-multiselect

Hi I keep getting a php error of Undefined Index on the posted variable called $_POST['stuff'] when I try to post my form of data via ajax... Please Help

**Form.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/main-temp.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
  <title>IT Request Form - FM-AD-103-01</title>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="'.$web_favicon.'">
  <link href="'.$web_css.'" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="'.$web_jquery.'" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="'.$web_jsres.'" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
  <script>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Script_Me" -->
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
          if ($("#employee").val() == 1) {
            var type = 1;
          } else {
            if ($("#type").val() == 1) {
              var type = 2;
            } else {
              var type = 3;
            }
          }
          var items = $("#requestItems").val();
          alert(items);
          var user = $("#user").val();
          var date = $("#requestedDate").val();
          var by = $("#requester").val();
          var loc = $("#loc").val();
          var dept = $("#requestDepartment").val();
          var items = $("#items").val();
          var just = $("#justify").val();
          var capabilities = $("#special").val();
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "post.php",
              data: {
                type: type,
                user: user,
                date: date,
                by: by,
                loc: loc,
                dept: dept,
                stuff: items,
                just: just,
                capa: capabilities,
                items: items
              }
            })
            .done(function(msg) {
              alert(msg);
              $("#thank1").show();
            });
        });
        $("#requestedDate").datepicker({
          beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          minDate: 5
        })

        function nonWorkingDates(date) {
          var day = date.getDay(),
            Sunday = 0,
            Monday = 1,
            Tuesday = 2,
            Wednesday = 3,
            Thursday = 4,
            Friday = 5,
            Saturday = 6;
          var closedDates = [
            [12, 22, 2014],
            [12, 23, 2014],
            [12, 24, 2014],
            [12, 25, 2014],
            [12, 26, 2014],
          ];
          var closedDays = [
            [Sunday],
            [Saturday]
          ];
          for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
            if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
              return [false];
            }

          }

          for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 &&
              date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] &&
              date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {
              return [false];
            }
          }

          return [true];
        }

      });
      $("#employee").change(function() {
        var type = $("#employee_type option:selected").text();
        if (type == "New Employee") {
          $("#requestedUser").text("New Employees Name:");
          $("#name").show();
        } else {
          $("#requestedUser").text("Current Employees Name:");
          $("#name").show();
        }
      });
      $("#submit").click(function() {
        $("#sending").toggle();
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        $("body").css({
          "overflow": "hidden"
        });
        setTimeout("window.close()", 5000);
      });
    });
     <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
  </script>
</head>
'; } ?>

<body style="overflow: scroll">
  <div class="container" style="width:800px;">
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="main" -->
    <form id="req">
      <div id="form_header" style="height:120px;">
        <div id="logo_main" title="Dyer & Butler Logo">
          <h3 style="padding:55px 0 0 7.5px;">IT Equipment/Software Requistion Form</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; width:200px; text-align:right; margin: 10px 20px;">
          FM-AD-103-01
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <fieldset>
        <span class="question">Please Choose Employee Type:</span>
        <select id="employee" class="options">
          <option value="" disabled selected>- - - - - - - Select your option - - - - - - -</option>
          <option value="1">New Employee</option>
          <option value="2">Current Employee</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset style="display:none;" id="name">
        <span class="question" id="requestedUser"></span>
        <input type="text" id="user" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <span class="question">Request Type:</span>
        <select class="options" id="type">
          <option value="" disabled selected>- - - - - - - Select your option - - - - - - -</option>
          <option value="1">Acquisition</option>
          <option value="2">Replacement</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="request_items">
        <span class="question">Requested Items</span>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <select style="float:right;" multiple="multiple" id="requestItems" name="my-select[]">
          <optgroup label="Hardware">
            <option value="mobile">Mobile Phone</option>
            <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
            <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="Operating System">
            <option value="XP">Windows XP</option>
            <option value="Windows 7">Windows 7</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="Software">
            <option>MS Project</option>
            <option>PDF Pro 10</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="Other">
            <option value='elem_1'>MiFi</option>
            <option>Printer</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <span style="float: left; width: 250px;margin: 10px; color: #f00; font-size: 10pt;">All equipment is subject to IT rules, don't always expect to get what you request it is subject to Job Title and Business needs</span>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <?php $SQL=m ysqli_query($db_data, "SELECT user_forename, user_surname FROM db_users WHERE user_login ='".$_SESSION[ 'db_user_token'][1]. "'"); $data=m ysqli_fetch_array($SQL); ?>
        <span class="question">Requested By:</span>
        <input type="text" id="requester" value="<?php echo $data['user_forename'] . " " . $data['user_surname']; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <span class="question">Date Equipment/Software required by:</span>
        <input type="text" id="requestedDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <span class="question">Location of Employee:</span>
        <select id="loc" class="options">
          <option value="" disabled selected>- - - - - - - Select your option - - - - - - -</option>
          <option>Head Office</option>
          <option>Heathrow (main)</option>
          <option>Heathrow (Snowbase)</option>
          <option>Gatwick</option>
          <option>Dyer & Butler Electrical</option>
          <option>London</option>
          <option>Milton Keynes</option>
          <option>Mersham</option>
          <option>Exeter</option>
          <option>Swindon</option>
          <option>Swansea</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <span class="question">Department of Employee:</span>
        <input type="text" id="requestDepartment" />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <span class="question">Will it be Connected to the Network?</span>
        <br/>
        <div style="float:right; width: 200px;">
          <input class="radio_cmd" type="radio" name="networking" />Yes
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; width: 200px;">
          <input class="radio_cmd" type="radio" name="networking" />No
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <span class="question">Justification:</span>
        <textarea id="justify" placeholder="Please Justify why replacement is required?"></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <span class="question">Special Capabilities:</span>
        <textarea id="special" placeholder="Please specify any special capabilities?"></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <script src="../../web_theme/Default/javascript/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script>
        $('#requestItems').multiSelect()
      </script>
      <input type="button" class="cmd" style="float: right; padding: 10 25;" id="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
include( "../../../db_conn/index.pas");
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/London'); 
$items=array(); $items=$_POST['stuff']; //get the values from the keeporder
mysqli_query( $db_data, "INSERT INTO 
        db_requests (
            `req_type`, 
            `req_user`, 
            `req_date`, 
            `req_by`, 
            `req_location`, 
            `req_dept`, 
            `req_items`, 
            `req_just`, 
            `req_capabilities`, 
            `req_day`
        ) 
        VALUES (
            '".$_POST[ 'type']. "', 
            '".$_POST[ 'user']. "', 
            '".$_POST[ 'date']. "', 
            '".$_POST[ 'by']. "', 
            '".$_POST[ 'loc']. "', 
            '".$_POST[ 'dept']. "', 
            '".$items. "', 
            '".$_POST[ 'just']. "', 
            '".$_POST[ 'capa']. "'
            , NOW()
        )
    "); ?>
```

It is just the Multiselect.js data that I can't get to post for some reason, but then the documentation on how to use it is good but it doesn't explain how to get the values/data out of it.

The Script is from this address: http://loudev.com/

Thank You to anyone that can help me... :-)

Comment: did you try to get the just one value at the time. Because I think you might have a problem with your paranthese in the VALUE( ... section

Comment: Everything else posts, just the stuff from the Multi-Select doesn't

Comment: I have made it so that the Multi-Select.val() is alerted using jquery and if you select any of the values it seems to alert it like this: val1, val2, val3, etc...

Comment: Are you saying that `$_POST['stuff']` is empty? If so , have you watched the AJAX request / response in your browser's console to see if the AJAX request is the problem? Doing `$items=array(); $items=$_POST['stuff'];` does not create an array called `$items`

Comment: I get a response which is alerted which says "Undefined Index stuff on line 6..." But the problem I have got is that data in the ajax request is correct for "stuff" which is alerted before posting!